# How to work with File Uploading onto Database in .NET Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am learning .NET and am trying to implement a file uploading feature on my web app.  I have a table in my SQL Server called 'Projects' and it has a column named 'FileUpload' which would contain the File Uploaded by the user and is of type VARBINARY(MAX).  The File would be a document such as a word doc. What type would the 'FileUpload' column be in EF?  And, how would I convert a stored procedure which returns a 'FileUpload' column and convert it into the entity framework's type?  This is the structure of what I have:

Project.cs

```
 [Table("Project")]
    public class Project
    {
        [Key] 
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public String ProjectName { get; set; }
        public String ProjectDescription { get; set; }
        public int FileUpload { get; set; }    //what type should it be?
        public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

Called in this stored procedure

```
public IEnumerable<Project> GetAllProjects(int SubCategoryId, int UserId)
        {
            List<Project> lstProjects = new List<Project>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllProjects", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(("@SubCategoryId"), SqlDbType.Int).Value = SubCategoryId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(("@UserId"), SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserId;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Project project = new Project();

                        project.ProjectName = rdr["ProjectName"].ToString();
                        project.ProjectDescription = rdr["ProjectDescription"].ToString();
                        project.FileUpload = rdr["FileUpload "].ToString();      //How would I rearrange this if it is not
                                                                                        //a string or an int?



                        lstProjects.Add(project);
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            return lstProjects;
        }
```

What will be the best approach to tackle implementing file uploading? Is my approach so far in the right direction with how I call the stored procedure and implement Project.cs? What type would FileUpload be in Project.cs and in the stored procedure call?

Comment: Be aware, using this approach, the whole file will be loaded into memory before it is persisted via your saving code. If you have multiple users uploading big files (>2/3mb) you will quickly hit serious problems with memory consumption on the server.

Comment: @RobertPerry would accessing and storing them via streaming using the async functions as shown in the link by David Browne (below) avoid this situation?

Answer (score 3):

For `varbinary(max)` use either `byte[]` or access it using [streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support).

Comment: What type would my FileUpload be in my Project.cs if I use streaming to access and store the files onto sql server?  Would byte[] work?